# MySQL : count, group by and order by : whole table data?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table with data :

```
id   one    two    three   four     five    six
------------------------------------------------
1    12     32     2       5        34       13
2    43     12     3       33       22       17
3    11     31     3       15       13       13
4    43     12     52      73       29       19
5    3      2      2       3        9        9
6    4      1      3       7        2        19
-------------------------------------------------
```

So i know how to count, group by and order by one column , like this :

`select one, count(one)
from table_numbers
group by one
order by count(one) desc`


Above query will give us :

```
one     count(one) 
-----------------
43      2
3       1
4       1
11      1
12      1
-----------------
```

So how can i get data like above for all columns in one single query ?

Like this :

```
One  Count(one) Two Count(two)  Three   Count(three)    Four    Count(four)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
43   2          12  2           3       3               73       1           
3    1          1   1           2       2               3        1           
4    1          2   1           52      1               5        1           
11   1          31  1           null    null            7        1          
12   1          32  1           null    null            15       1          
null null      null null        null    null            33       1          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Now is there any way to do it in one single sql query ? May be using joins or inline views or anything else? Or Is this possible in single query ?**

[update] I want to count duplicate values from every column and sort it in descending order.

[UPDATE] In case you want to use table data :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_numbers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `one` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `two` int(2) NOT NULL,  `three` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `four` int(2) NOT NULL,  `five` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `six` int(2) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `col_one` (`one`),  KEY `col_two` (`two`),
  KEY `col_three` (`three`),  KEY `col_four` (`four`),
  KEY `col_five` (`five`),  KEY `col_six` (`six`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `table_numbers` (`id`, `one`, `two`, `three`, `four`, `five`, `six`)
VALUES
(1, 12, 32, 2, 5, 34, 13),(2, 43, 12, 3, 33, 22, 17),(3, 11, 31, 3, 15, 13, 13),
(4, 43, 12, 52, 73, 29, 19),(5, 3, 2, 2, 3, 9, 9),(6, 4, 1, 3, 7, 2, 19);
```

Bundle of thanks in advance !

Jay :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to get colum count in one query:

```
(select 'one' as col, one as item, count(one) as count from table_numbers group by one) UNION
(select 'two', two, count(two) from table_numbers group by two) UNION
(select 'three', three, count(three) from table_numbers group by three) UNION
(select 'four', four, count(four) from table_numbers group by four) UNION
(select 'five', five, count(five) from table_numbers group by five) UNION
(select 'six', six, count(six) from table_numbers group by six) UNION
ORDER BY col, count DESC
```

It is much more complex If you want summary in columns (example for 3 columns):

```
SELECT tone.item as One, tone.count as `Count(one)`, ttwo.item as Two, ttwo.count as `Count(two)`, tthree.item as Three, tthree.count as `Count(three)` 
FROM 
  (SELECT @rownumtmp:=@rownumtmp+1 as rownum 
   FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT col, count 
     FROM (
      (select 'one' as col, one as item, count(one) as count from table_numbers group by one) UNION
      (select 'two', two, count(two) from table_numbers group by two) UNION
      (select 'three', three, count(three) from table_numbers group by three)) tmp) tmp2, 
    (SELECT @rownumtmp:=0) r) tmp2 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 as rownum, item, count FROM (SELECT one as item, count(one) as count from  table_numbers group by one ORDER BY count DESC, one) d, (SELECT @rownum1:=0) r)  tone ON tmp2.rownum=tone.rownum LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 as rownum, item, count FROM (SELECT two as item, count(two) as count from  table_numbers group by two ORDER BY count DESC, two) d, (SELECT @rownum2:=0) r)  ttwo ON tmp2.rownum=ttwo.rownum LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT @rownum3:=@rownum3+1 as rownum, item, count FROM (SELECT three as item, count(three) as count from  table_numbers group by three ORDER BY count DESC, three) d, (SELECT @rownum3:=0) r)  tthree ON tmp2.rownum=tthree.rownum 
WHERE tone.item IS NOT NULL OR ttwo.item IS NOT NULL OR tthree.item IS NOT NULL
```

Result of above query will be look like this:

```
One  Count(one) Two Count(two)  Three   Count(three)
-----------------------------------------------------   
43   2          12  2           3       3            
3    1          1   1           2       2       
4    1          2   1           52      1        
11   1          31  1           null    null            
12   1          32  1           null    null                
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, Yes its very close what i need but its only showing three rows.

Comment: I fixed second query. Test on your sample data returns exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to mean this?:

```
select one, two, three, four, five, six, count(1) 
from table_numbers group by one, two, three, four, five, six
order by count(1) desc
```

Are you trying to find duplicates?

Comment: Yes trying to find duplicates. Above query not working right, i need to find the number who occur most in a column.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the possibility of doing this in single query!!
A query traverses the table only once when executed.. in your case it need to count
more than one columns.

Comment: So what you suggest, to write six different queries to get required data ?

Comment: yep!! Upto my knowledge, its the only easy result yielding solution. Other would be a complex set of sub queries and joins and would be costing heavier.. Work your trade off formula..

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
SELECT
    one AS val, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM ( 
    SELECT one FROM table_numbers UNION ALL
    SELECT two FROM table_numbers UNION ALL
    SELECT three FROM table_numbers UNION ALL
    SELECT four FROM table_numbers UNION ALL
    SELECT five FROM table_numbers UNION ALL
    SELECT six FROM table_numbers 
) x GROUP BY one ORDER BY c DESC;
```

Comment: @Iqez, Your query giving count from all table data, i need this from every column separately.

Comment: @Jay, each column may not have same number of rows. So I'm not sure what do you want exactly. Can you describe the desire result that you want?

Comment: @Iqez, Yes, Please check question again. I have update it according to what i exactly want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see that can be done is...export your data from the table as one long string of integer. i.e. a flat file and import the data back to a new table as one field. Write sql statement to extrapolate the duplicate to a new field and do a total count. Do the same until the imported data in field is empty. Hope that help.